# In Jupyter notebook, how do I arrange subroutines in order to write a project efficiently?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to write a program using Python in Jupiter. To make things easy, it'd be better off writing a few subroutines (functions) and probably some user-defined classes first before writing the main script. How do I arrange them in Jupiter? Just each sub function/class for a new line and write sequentially and then write main script below to call subroutines? I just wonder if this is the right way to use Jupyter.

I am new to Jupyter and Python, but in Matlab, for instance, I would create a folder which contains all sub functions to be used. And I will also write a script inside the same folder to call these functions to accomplish the task. However, how do I achieve this in Python using Jupyter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best thing to do for repeated code you want all your notebook to access is to add it to the profile directory. The notebook will load all scripts from that directory in order, so it's recommended you name files `01-<projname>.py` if you want them to load in a certain order. All files in that directory will be loaded via `exec` which executes the file as though it were in your context, it's not a module load so globals will squash each other and all of the model context will be in your local namespace afterwards (similar to an `import *` effect).

To find your profile directory the docs recommend you use `ipython locate profile <my_profile_name>`. This will tell you where you can place the script.

Comment: I just entered `ipython locate` in the Windows command prompt, and I got the path **C:\Users\Tom\.ipython**. And if I open the web-based notebook, the documents are just stored in the path **C:\Users\Tom**. So I wonder when you said profile directory, do you mean **C:\Users\Tom** in my case? Also, are you saying that if functions and classes are created in one notebook file (with a .ipynb extension) under **C:\Users\Tom**, then they can be used directly in other notebook files under **C:\Users\Tom**? Thanks! @Pyrce

Comment: The located path will be where custom scripts get loaded into each notebook. You won't be saving notebooks, but rather python files with the functions you want access to. So you'd save a file with a `.py` extension into the `.ipython` directory and anything you define inside that `.py` file will be available in your notebooks.

Comment: So I created a .py file under path **C:\Users\Tom\.ipython**, and then I tried to call the function defined in this .py file in a .ipynb notebook file I created under **C:\Users\Tom**, however, I got the error **NameError: name 'qqq' is not defined**. 'qqq' is my function's name. Where is the problem?

Comment: FYI, under the path  **C:\Users\Tom\.ipython** where my .py file is stored, there are also folders named **extensions**, **nbextentions**, **profile_default**. Did I put the .py file in the right directory?@Pyrce

Comment: Ah yes, try adding them to the `profile_default` directory -- if you create specific profiles you'd need to add the files to those subdirectories instead.

Comment: @NicholasLiu There might also be a `startup` directory inside that `profile_default` depending on versions and setup which has all the code that's loaded on startup

Comment: I tried to add the .py file to the profile_default directory but still got the same error. Are you saying to only add .py file to the **C:\Users\Tom.ipython\profile_default** directory? Also, what do you mean by **specific profiles** and **subdirectories**? @Pyrce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101026/discussion-between-nicholas-liu-and-pyrce).

Comment: This way, the code will be loaded for every notebook you load, not only for the notebooks you choose for. Furthermore, I prefer to keep my project code strictly separated from ipython configuration files.

Comment: That's nice and all but you didn't need to downvote a valid answer to the question just because you have a different preference (and answer...)

Comment: This method has as drawback that it severely reduce the portability of your notebooks. When you want to use them on another computer (or even on the same, with another account), you not only have to synchronize the notebook, but also the included files, that are located in a separate (and hidden) directory.

Comment: I would argue it is a lot more portable than storing in a global directory. You can move your notebook folder easily in isolation with all its dependencies present. Just move the notebook directory, done. There are more sophisticated things you could do, but by then you probably are doing something outside the standard scope of notebooks. I use notebook directories inside repositories all the time for exploration and passing dependent files is not hard at all when I need to.

Answer (score 2):

I use notebooks mainly for data analysis. My workflow is as follows: During development, I declare all my routines in notebook cells. When I need the same functions for the next dataset, I quite often copy-paste them to the new notebook. Quite often, I have to adapt the functions slightly for the new dataset. When it turned out that I use functions often in may notebooks, I create a separate module (yust a python file with the functions copy-pasted in it) and put this my "global" python directory (`~/python`) on my system. This function is in my `$pythonpath`, and hence, in the next notebook I can simply say

```
from read_data_functions import square_measurement, long_run
```